# Fully disable man-db?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-server

Today I noticed that one of my hosts was stuck on:

```
systemd[1]: Starting Rotate log files...
systemd[1]: Starting Daily man-db regeneration...
```

Is it okay to stop those updates? Otherwise I need to check every day if the machine is healthy or not.

Answer (score 5):

Not the question being asked, but for anyone else who lands here trying to figure out how to disable the automatic update every time you install a package:

```
$ sudo rm /var/lib/man-db/auto-update
```

Removing this file disables the auto-update every time you install a package and replaces it with a warning that the index is not being updated.

Why this is not (as far as I can tell) mentioned in any of the man-db documentation is beyond me.  The index is still updated daily by a systemd timer / service (at least on Ubuntu 22.04 desktop, haven't checked others).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this qualifies as 'Fully disable' but It may get you to where you want to go.

I was getting annoyed by apt updates with delays at "Processing triggers for man-db".

But I sometimes need the man pages.

And since there doesn't seem to be a stand-alone 'man' package, I can't simply remove the 'man-db' package.

My solution, for better or worse, was to move the 'mandb' executable out of the way and substitute in a copy of 'true'

On my system:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/mandb /usr/bin/mandb-OFF
sudo cp -p /bin/true /usr/bin/mandb 
sudo rm -r /var/cache/man
```

This is easy to undo if the need arises.  And I deleted the /var/cach/man directory, as it is no longer needed and recovered megabytes of space.

Any 'man' pages you need are grabbed from the source man directory and decompressed on the fly.  No more caching means a slight inefficiency, but with today's speeder processors and disks, its minimal.

A caveat: Anytime you get a man-db package update, your modifications will be  overwritten.  Either apt-hold the 'man-db' package or be prepared to redo this at the whim of the 'man-db' package maintainers and distribution managers.

After this mod, you will still see the apt update line "Processing triggers for man-db" fly by but it's a zero second thing. :-)

And the midnight routines will just go right thru the dummy mandb update.

Good Luck.

Comment: Nice! I will definitely try it.